# jquery link tag href with onclick requires two clicks to load ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onclick

i am coding a ajax page that when a jquery selector id is fired it passed the parameter via onclick and does a $.getJSON then returns the data on the div. it works but it requires two clicks to load the content! it is suppose to only load with one click! any help would be appreciated. 
heres the code:

```
function services(theid) {

$('#open').on('click', function(){


   $.getJSON('process_serv.php',{thevar: theid}, function(data){

    $('.services').html(data.name + "-" +  data.charge);
   });
 });


  }
```

---

```
<a href="#"onclick="services('<?php echo $id?>'); return false"       
id="open" >hi</a> 
<div class="services">
</div>
<div class="times">
</div>
<div class="details">
```

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "labookin");

if(isset($_GET['thevar'])){

$id = $_GET['thevar'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE bizid='$id'";

$the = $con->query($query);

$row = $the->fetch_assoc();

echo json_encode($row);


}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attching the click handler on first click, then running it on the second click. Change your JS code to this:

```
function services(theid) {
    $.getJSON('process_serv.php',{thevar: theid}, function(data){
        $('.services').html(data.name + "-" +  data.charge);
    });
}
```